# How to customize some default PHP error message thrown to user

Tags: php, customization, fatal-error

I encounter the situation as follows:
My system sometimes gets default two specific errors and display to user's screen. But now, my users would like to display these kind of error messages in a friendly way, not default ones. The two types of message are:

> **1. Allowed memory size of...**
>
> **2. Maximum execution time of...**

I've already tried to use `set_error_handler("someFunction")`, but it doesn't handle these kinds of errors. Please note that they are `'Fatal Error(s)'` types.

I'd appreciate it if you help me out.

Thanks a great deal!

Comment: of course if you know you are getting theses errors you should fix the cause not the symptom

Comment: Thanks nogad for your prompt reply.